# SVM and cross validation

Tags: svm, cross-validation

The problem is as follows. When I do support vector machine training, suppose I have already performed cross validation on 10000 training points with a Gaussian kernel and have obtained the best parameter C and \sigma. Now I have another 40000 new training points and since I don't want to waste time on cross validation, I stick to the original C and \sigma that I obtained from the first 10000 points, and train the entire 50000 points on these parameters. Is there any potentially major problem with this? It seems that for C and \sigma in some range, the final test error wouldn't be that bad, and thus the above process seems okay.

Comment: What do you mean "performed cross validation on 10000 training points"? What was your validation size, and did you only perform CV on that exact 10,000 points?

Comment: Well this is not a real case. When I say 10,000 I'm really saying the size of the original training set. By cross validation you can think of it as making a 10-fold cv to choose the parameters that produces the least cross validation error. And yes, as I said in my question I only perform CV on the first 10000 points, and use the parameters to train my sum with the entire 50000 training points.

Comment: I don't really see anything wrong with it. CV gives a closer unbiased estimate of the testing error than the training error itself. So long as your initial 10,000 points and the remaining 40,000 are all sampled from the same population (i.e. they all came from the same source), it should work fine. Of course, using more data in CV will give an even closer estimate, but sacrifices are to be made.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Another question: If I use the original $\sigma$ in the Gaussian kernel, will it be possible that the matrix $K$ becomes singular or almost singular when I retrain with the entire data set?

Answer (score 0):

There is one major pitfal of such appraoch. Both `C` and `sigma` are **data dependant**. In particular, it can be shown, that optimal `C` strongly depends on the size of the training set. So once you make your training data 5 times bigger, even if it brings no "new" knowledge - you should still find new `C` to get the exact same model as before. So, you can do such procedure, but keep in mind, that best parameters for smaller training set **do not have to** be the best for the bigger one (even though, they sometimes still are).

To better see the picture. If this procedure would be fully "ok" than why not fit `C` on even smaller data? 5 times? 25 times smaller? Mayone on one single point per class? 10,000 may seem "a lot", but it depends on the problem considered. In many real life domains this is just a "regular" (biology) or even "very small" (finance) dataset, so you won't be sure, if your procedure is fine **for this particular problem** until you test it.